# Why is third printstream println() command skipped?

Tags: java, printstream

I've got a server/client program that I am writing in which a server sends messages to a client and vise versa.  It works perfectly, except for the `out.println` statements in the `printRemoteAddress()` method.  `"HELLO1"` and `"HELLO2"` print to the client, but `"HELLO3`" does not.

My question is, why does `"HELLO3"` not print to the client, but the first two do?

SERVER CODE:

```
class Worker extends Thread {

Socket sock;
Worker (Socket s) {sock = s;}


    public void run() {

        PrintStream out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            try {
                String name;
                name = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Looking up " + name);
                printRemoteAddress(name, out);
            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.out.println("Server read error");
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {System.out.println(ioe);}
    }

        static void printRemoteAddress (String name, PrintStream out) {
            try {
                out.println("HELLO1");
                out.println("HELLO2");
                out.println("HELLO3");
                InetAddress machine = InetAddress.getByName(name);
            } catch(UnknownHostException ex) {          
                out.println ("Failed in attempt to look up " + name);
            }
        }




public class InetServer {

public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {
    int q_len = 6;
    int port = 2000;
    Socket sock;

    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(port, q_len);

    System.out.println
        ("Inet server 1.8 starting up, listening at port 2000.\n");
    while (true) {
        sock = servsock.accept();
        new Worker(sock).start();
    }   
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
public class InetClient {

public static void main (String args[]) {
    String serverName;
    if (args.length < 1) serverName = "localhost";
    else serverName = args[0];

    System.out.println("Inet Client, 1.0.\n");
    System.out.println("Using server: " + serverName + ", Port: 2000");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        String name;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter hostname of IP address: ");
            System.out.flush();
            name = in.readLine();
            if (name.indexOf("stop") < 0)
                getRemoteAddress(name, serverName);
        } while (name.indexOf("stop") < 0);
        System.out.println("Process stopped.");;
    } catch (IOException x) {x.printStackTrace();}
}

static void getRemoteAddress (String name, String serverName) {
    Socket sock;
    BufferedReader fromServer;
    PrintStream toServer;
    String textFromServer;

    try {
        sock = new Socket(serverName, 2000);

        fromServer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

        toServer = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        toServer.println(name);
        toServer.flush();

        for (int i = 1; i <3; i++) {
            textFromServer = fromServer.readLine();
            if (textFromServer != null) System.out.println(textFromServer);
        }
        sock.close();
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.out.println("Socket error.");
        x.printStackTrace();    
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: You need to check the result of `readLine()` for null before you do anything else with it, and close the socket if you get it.

Comment: In your client code: `for (int i = 1; i <3; i++) {` only iterates 2 times. Write it out on paper and see. Either start with i at zero or use <=

Comment: Thank you.  I changed it to <= and that fixed the problem.  As EJP stated, the issue was with the client code and not the server code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 1; i <3; i++) {
```

Bzzzzzzzzt. This iterates twice, not three times. It should be

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
```

In fact it would make more sense not to hardwire the 3 in at all:

```
while ((textFromServer = fromServer.readLine()) != null {
    System.out.println(textFromServer);
}
```

The `println()` isn't 'skipped', but [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) is buffered and doesn't auto-flush on newlines. You can construct it with a second parameter so as to do that, or call `flush()` as appropriate, or use a `PrintWriter`.

You should also close the `PrintStream/PrintWriter`, not the `Socket`.

Comment: Even when I construct it with autoflosh (`out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream(), true);`) it still doesn't work.  Nor does putting a `out.flush()` command in between each `out.println()` statement.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your client code, which you haven't posted. Edit it into your question.